# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease' de Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbw; Alguem saberia esse erro?

Tags: android, android-studio

No meu Android Studio esta dando o seguinte erro ao tentar fazer uma apk para loja:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
>   Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbw;

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse erro.

Aqui tem as dependencias do meu projeto no build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 

        {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })

            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'

            compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.10'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'

            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.1'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1' 
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:9.6.1'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.6.1' 

            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1' 
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1' 
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'  
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1' 

            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


        }
```

Comment: Você está utilizando Multidex? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: Não uso o multidex, nesse caso e necessario?

Comment: Talvez seja porque você utiliza bilbiotecas de support, play-services e firebase que possuem muitas chamadas à métodos. Quando a aplicação possui mais de 64k chamadas à métodos então você precisa do multidex. É simples de habilitar, na documentação oficial acima explica bem

Comment: Leia isso aqui: [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pelo que percebemos, você está utilizando muitas bibliotecas externas. Considerando isso, temos que talvez, eu digo talvez, esteja excedendo o limite total de métodos a serem referenciados no seu projeto.

**Explicação:** [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

> Os Arquivos de Aplicativo Android (APK) contêm arquivos bytecode
>   executáveis no formato Dalvik Executable (DEX), que contêm código
>   compilado, usado para executar seu aplicativo. As especificação Dalvik
>   Executables limitam o total de número de métodos que podem ser
>   referenciados dentro de um único arquivo DEX a 65.536, incluindo os
>   métodos de framework Android, métodos de biblioteca, e os métodos em
>   seu próprio código. Para ultrapassar este limite você terá que
>   configurar o processo de compilação de seu aplicativo para gerar mais
>   de um arquivo DEX, configuração essa conhecida como multidex.

**Solução:**

1. Você deve tentar formatar as dependências (bibliotecas), enxugar o máximo possível, do seu código para remover as classes em excesso para tentar não exceder o limite. Em seguida, sincronize *Gradle* em **Android Studio** e verificar se ocorrerá o erro novamente. Se não resolver, vá para a segunda opção.
2. Adicionar em `build.gradle` (módulo app).

> ```
> android {
>    ...
>    defaultConfig {
>       ...
>       multiDexEnabled true
>    }
> }
> ```

Vários ótimos desenvolvedores já escreveram sobre esse tópico, e alguns exemplos estão aqui:

- [Developer.android Multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)
- [Tom Reznik, limite de métodos do DEX](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2014/10/30/android-and-the-dex-64k-methods-limit/)
- [Sebastiano Gottardo ultrapassa o limite de 65k](https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71)