# Erro ao gerar APK - app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tentando transformar minha aplicação em APK, para entrega de TCC e estou tendo o erro seguinte:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease' de Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbw; Alguem saberia esse erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157934/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease-de-lcom)

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo de um `Clean Project` no seu projeto e após isso adicione no seu arquivo **build.grandle**:

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```